# about packages in Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, installation-package

When i open this folder

```
  /var/cache/apt/archives
```

I found a big list of all **the deb files** of all the programs that I've installed before so my questions is :

> Is it possible to use these files to install again the programs in other computer ?
> If yes so 
>   How to install them ? because eclipse for example have more than one file , so wich one i will use ?
>   And why Linux don't delete the installation files after installing a program ?

this is a part from the list :

```
....
chromium_37.0.2062.120-1~deb7u1_amd64.deb<br>
chromium-inspector_37.0.2062.120-1~deb7u1_all.deb
codeblocks_10.05-2.1_amd64.deb
codeblocks-common_10.05-2.1_all.deb
eclipse_3.8.0~rc4-1_all.deb
eclipse-jdt_3.8.0~rc4-1_all.deb
eclipse-pde_3.8.0~rc4-1_amd64.deb
eclipse-platform_3.8.0~rc4-1_amd64.deb
eclipse-platform-data_3.8.0~rc4-1_all.deb
eclipse-rcp_3.8.0~rc4-1_amd64.deb
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a cleanup routine.  `sudo apt-get clean`

Linux doesn't delete the files automatically to prevent needing to redownload the file if uninstalled and reinstalled.  Many of these packages might simply be for dependencies.

If you want files removed automatically (especially for older versions).  Run `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: So you mean that i can use these files to install my programs again , so how to install eclipse for example there is more than one deb file there , which one i will use ?? :) and thank you Sir :)

Comment: The idea of clean, autoclean, and autoremove is to delete files that are no longer relevant.  When you update a package, you generally don't need the old one anymore.  Just install eclipse and let `apt-get` handle which version.

Comment: @KhalilBz - If you look at the installed packages in `synaptic` you will see a description of each. Some will be meta-packages, which don't install anything themselves, but bring in all the packages required as dependencies.

Comment: i understand from you that these different files mean different updates , OK , but i want to explain for you my idea : i want to get all the installation files and use them for other installation because i have a very slow internet connection and if i will use apt-get install again as you said , it will take a very long time , that's why i'm asking to use these files again :) sorry if my questions are bothering you :) and thank you so much :)

Comment: ok if i will copy all of them and put them in the directory /var/cache/apt/archives of the other system and use apt-get install eclipse will it install the packages without downloading them again :) thank you Sir

Comment: @KhalilBz - You should roll your question back to its original revision then ask a different question how to install your already downloaded .deb files otherwise you risk making this answer invalid if you keep changing the answer.

Comment: ok thank you anyway , i answered my question , yeah it' will work , because i used --download-only with the apt-get command on filezilla and then I replaced the packages from the directory /var/cache/apt/archives and when i executed apt-get install filezilla it's start downloading the files ,then I stopped it and returned the files to the archives directory and I executed apt-get install filezilla and it started the installation directly , Thank you anyway :)